# Postgresql, Get the top 5 products that have increased in value from yesterday to today, returning the delta

Tags: postgresql

I have a `pricing` table that contains the pricing data for products. There are around 600 unique `product_id`, each currently having 4 days worth of pricing data, which will eventually go up to 30 days. The table below is a small subset of the data to represent that table structure:

| date | product_id | price_trend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-21 | 1 | 0.08 |
| 2022-08-22 | 1 | 0.18 |
| 2022-08-23 | 1 | 0.30 |
| 2022-08-21 | 2 | 0.15 |
| 2022-08-22 | 2 | 0.20 |
| 2022-08-23 | 2 | 0.22 |

So in my script, for each `product_id` I am trying to get yesterdays `price_trend` and todays `price_trend` and then calculate the `price_delta` between the two. I then `order by` `price_delta` and limit the results to 5.

I am having some issues as in some cases yesterdays `price_trend` is 0 and then todays price trend is 0.50 for example. This does not mean that the price trend has increased, but mostly likely that `price_trend` was not gathered yesterday for whatever reason.

Now I would like to remove any records where `price_trend` for today or yesterday equals 0, however, when I add `AND pricing.trend_price > 0` the value return is just null instead.

**Script:**

```sql
SELECT 
    magic_sets_cards.name,
    (SELECT pricing.trend_price 
     FROM pricing 
     WHERE pricing.product_id = magic_sets_cards_identifiers.mcm_id 
        AND pricing.date = (SELECT MAX(date) - INTERVAL '2 DAY' FROM pricing)
        AND pricing.trend_price > 0) AS price_yesterday,
    (SELECT pricing.trend_price 
    FROM pricing 
    WHERE pricing.product_id = magic_sets_cards_identifiers.mcm_id
        AND pricing.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM pricing)
        AND pricing.trend_price > 0) AS price_today, 
    ((SELECT pricing.trend_price 
      FROM pricing 
      WHERE pricing.product_id = magic_sets_cards_identifiers.mcm_id 
        AND pricing.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM pricing)) - 
    (SELECT pricing.trend_price 
     FROM pricing 
     WHERE pricing.product_id = magic_sets_cards_identifiers.mcm_id 
        AND pricing.date = (SELECT MAX(date) - INTERVAL '2 DAY' FROM pricing))) AS price_delta
FROM magic_sets
    JOIN magic_sets_cards ON magic_sets_cards.set_id = magic_sets.id
    JOIN magic_sets_cards_identifiers ON magic_sets_cards_identifiers.card_id = magic_sets_cards.id
    JOIN pricing ON pricing.product_id = magic_sets_cards_identifiers.mcm_id
WHERE magic_sets.code = '2X2'
    AND pricing.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM pricing)
ORDER BY price_delta DESC
LIMIT 5
```

**Results:**

| name | price_yesterday | price_today | price_delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Fiery Justice" | null | 0.50 | 0.50 |
| "Hostage Taker" | 3.50 | 4.00 | 0.50 |
| "Damnation" | 17.02 | 17.33 | 0.31 |
| "Bring to Light" | 0.42 | 0.72 | 0.30 |
| "City of Brass" | 17.41 | 17.68 | 0.27 |

I would like to get it so that the "Fiery Justice" in this example is just ignored.

Comment: Your input and your output don't match: You have just 2 unique id's in the input, but end up with 5 unique names. Could you create a complete example on https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14 ?

Comment: @FrankHeikens The real input data contains 600 unique `product_id` each with 4 days of pricing data. This will eventually go up to 30 days worth of pricing data. I will look into the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the use of rank() you can get the output ., Look into...

Query without null rows :

```
with cte as (Select
product_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN price_trend ELSE null END) today, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN price_trend ELSE null END) yesterday,
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) as diff
FROM (
SELECT
product_id,
price_trend, 
date, 
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date DESC) as rank
FROM tableName where price_trend>0 and  date between current_date-5 and current_date-4) p
WHERE rank in (1,2) 
GROUP BY product_id
) select * from cte where (case when today is null or yesterday is null then 'NULL' else 'VALID' end)!='NULL'
```

Query with null values :

```
Select
product_id, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) today, 
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) yesterday,
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) -
SUM(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN price_trend ELSE 0 END) as diff
FROM (
SELECT
product_id,
price_trend, 
date, 
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY date DESC) as rank
FROM tableName where date between current_date-5 and current_date-4) p
WHERE rank in (1,2)
GROUP BY product_id
```

Change the condition :

where date between current_date-3 and current_date-2

OUTPUT :

```
product_id  today   yesterday   diff
1   0.06    0.02    0.04
2   0.64    0.62    0.02
```

```
CREATE TABLE tableName 
(
    date    date,
    product_id  int,
    price_trend numeric(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-21 ', '1 ', '0.02');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-22 ', '1 ', '0.06');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-23 ', '1 ', '0.10');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-24 ', '1 ', '0.13');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-25 ', '1 ', '0.18');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-26 ', '1 ', '0.30');

INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-21 ', '2 ', '0.62');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-22 ', '2 ', '0.64');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-23 ', '2 ', '0.69');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-24 ', '2 ', '0.78');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-25 ', '2 ', '0.88');
INSERT INTO tableName (date ,product_id ,price_trend) VALUES ('2022-08-26 ', '2 ', '0.90');
```

Comment: Hello, this works but still presents the same problem I was seeing. For some of the results returned `today` is `5.00` and `yesterday` is `0.00`. This suggests that the product's `price_trend` has increased by 5, but is more likely that there was no data for that product yesterday. I would like to remove any products from the set of data where `today` or `yesterday` `price_trend` is 0

Comment: 'remove any products from the set of data where today or yesterday price_trend is 0' condition added in the new query.